# Command to bypass hyperref error explanation

Tags: errors, hyperref, warnings

I had warning in my project

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' is turned off because \thepage is undefined.
```

I used command before document class.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels=false}{hyperref}
```

Can somebody explain me what is exactly happening when I use this command? 
I have to explain it in my project. It's just the trick to avoid the error by turning labels to false?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is difficult for anyone to help without more details. Can you please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should be a minimal piece of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I dont have any problem :)  i just need explanation of "\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels=false}{hyperref}" And I did not find it  anywhere

Comment: I suppose the real question is, why is `\thepage` undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `hyperref` generates invisible anchors based on the printed page number (which might be different from the physical page count) in the PDF stream which can be used to link to pages.

If `\thepage` (the standard page printing macro) is undefined in some non standard document class then hyperref can not generate the internal page identifier and would warn unless you use the `pdfpagelabels=false` option to disable the whole mechanism.